# Swapping out databases?

Tags: database, data-access-layer, data-access

It seems like the goal of a lot of ORM tools and custom data access layers (DAO pattern, etc.) is to abstract the database to the point where you could supposedly swap out the entire database system with minimal work.

Following the common DAL patterns is usually a good idea in code, but it seems like it would never be minimal work to swap out a database.  (Cost, training, data migration, etc.)

Does anyone have any experience with swapping out one database for another in a large system, and dealing with the implications in code?  Is it worth it to worry about abstracting the actual database from your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question 1:** Does anyone have any experience with
>   swapping out one database for another
>   in a large system, and dealing with
>   the implications in code?

Yes we tried it. Our customer is using a large MS Access based Delphi client server application. After about five years we considered switching to SQL Server. We analyzed the problem and concluded that swapping the database would be very costly and provide only a few advantages. Customer decided not to swap the database. The application is still running fine and the customer is still happy.

Note that:

- MS Access is only being used for data storage and report generation.
- The server application ensures that MS Access is only being accessed on the server. Normal multi-user MS Access applications will transfer large chunks of the Access database over the network - resulting in slow and unreliable database functionality. This is not the case for this application. Client <> Server <> MS Access. Only the server application communicates with the MS Access database. Actually the Server has exclusive access to the MS Access database. No other computer can open to the MS Access database. Conclusion: MS Access is being used as a true RDBMS,  Relational DataBase Management System - please no flaming about MS Access being inferior and unstable - it has been running fine for more than 10 years.

The most important issues you will have to consider:

1. **SQL statements**: (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT, CREATE TABLE) and make sure they would be compatible with the SQL database. It's amazing how much all the RDBMS differ in the details (date formats, number formats, search formats, string formats, join syntax, create table syntax, stored procedures, user defined functions, (auto) primary keys, etc.)
2. **Report generation**: Depending on your database you might be using a different reporting tool. Our customer has over 200 complex reports. Converting all these reports is very time consuming.
3. **Performance**: all RDBMS have different performances in different environments. Normally performance optimalisations are very much RDBMS dependent.
4. **Costs**: the costs of tools, developers, server and user licenses varies greatly. It ranges from free to very expensive. Free does not mean cheap and expensive does not always equate to good. A cost/value comparison will have to be made.
5. **Experience**: making the best use of your RDBMS requires experience. If you have to develop for an "unknown" RDBMS your productivity will suffer.

> **Question 2:** Is it worth it to worry about
>   abstracting the actual database from
>   your code?

Yes. In an ideal world, swapping a database would just be adjusting the data connection string. In the real world this is not possible because all databases are different. They all have tables and SQL support but the differences are in the details. If you can keep the differences of the databases shielded through abstraction - please do so. Make a list of the databases you need to support. Check the selected database systems for the differences. Provide centralized code to handle the differences. Support one RDBMS and provide stubs for future support of other RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that the purpose is to be able to swap out databases, and I think you are correct in showing some suspicion about ORMs leading towards that goal.

However, I would still use an ORM, as it abstracts away the details of data access. Isn't this the goal of object oriented programming? Keep your concerns separated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the primary use case for database abstraction (via ORM tools) is to be able to ship a product that works with multiple database brands.  I believe it's a rarer occurrence for a company to switch between database vendors, but that's still one of the use cases.

I've worked jobs where we started out using MySQL for monetary reasons (think a startup) and, one we started making money, wanted to switch to Oracle.  We didn't end up making the switch, but it was nice to have the option.

Still, ORM tools are not a completely leak-less abstractions and I *know* our migration still would have been painful and costly.  It totally depends on what you are building, but it has been my experience that -- for performance reasons, usually -- you end up either working around your ORM solution or exploiting vendor-specific features at some point.

Comment: +1 - if you want to be able to switch databases easily, ORM is only one of the things you need. It still provides useful abstraction even if you don't plan to switch.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've seen a database switch was from HSQL during early development to Oracle as the project progressed. The ORM made this easy.

I often use the DAO pattern to swap out data services (from a database to web service or to swap a web service to a test stub).

For ORM I don't think the goal is to enable you to switch databases - it is to hide you from the complexities of different database implementations and removing the need to worry about the fine details of translating from relational to object represenations of your data.

By having someone smart write an ORM that handles caching, only updates fields that have changed, groups updates, etc I don't need to. Although in the cases where I need something special I can still revert to SQL if I want.